# Curiously recurring template - variation

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

Regarding [CRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) if I want to implement a slight variation of it (using template template parameter) I get a compile error:

```
template <template <typename T> class Derived>
class Base
{
public:
    void CallDerived()
    {
        Derived* pT = static_cast<Derived*> (this);
        pT->Action(); // instantiation invocation error here
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived: public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    void Action()
    {
    }
};
```

I am not exactly sure one would chose this form (that does not compile for me) instead of using this though (this works)

```
template <typename Derived>
class Base
{
public:
    void CallDerived()
    {
        Derived* pT = static_cast<Derived*> (this);
        pT->Action();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived: public Base<Derived<T>>
{
public:
    void Action()
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should compile as well. We just need to get the other template parameter specified explicitly

```
 template <typename T, template <typename T> class Derived>
 class Base
 {
 public:
     void CallDerived()
     {
        Derived<T>* pT = static_cast<Derived<T>*> (this);
        pT->Action(); // instantiation invocation error here
     }
 };

template<typename T>
class Derived: public Base<T,Derived>
{
public:
    void Action()
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Quite interesting one has to be explicit about typename T in declaration twice... Don't really understand why

Comment: Just realized that derived has to transmit it's T parameter also.

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, the class template actually takes *template template parameter*, not just *template parameter*, as you've written:

```
template <template <typename T> class Derived>
class Base
{
     //..
};
```

So this code doesn't make sense:

```
Derived* pT = static_cast<Derived*> (this);
pT->Action(); // instantiation invocation error here
```

Here `Derived` is a template template argument which needs template argument which you didn't provided to it. In fact, in the `CallDerived()` function, you cannot know the *type* you need to provide to it, in order to do what you intend to do.

The second approach is the correct solution. Use it.

Comment: But how do I provide the template argument in first case.. Using derived<T> * pt does not work either

Comment: @Ghita: `T` is not known in the base class. Other solution has explained as to how you can pass `T` to the base. But that is not needed, as you should go for the second solution.

Comment: Sometimes T is needed in the Base class. E.g. when having a member `T Action();` For sure, you could use a traits class that gives a T for every Derived class, but sometimes you want T and Derived to vary independently. In that case, you want the [first] approach with a template + a template-template parameter.