# C++: Pure virtual type

Tags: c++, scala, templates, generic-programming

I'm exploring template shenanigans in C++ (C++11), and one thing I'd like to have is a pure virtual type in an abstract class. This would be like Scala's [abstract types](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/105). In C++ I'd want to do something like the following:

```
struct Base {
  // Says any concrete subclass must define Type, but doesn't
  // require that it be anything in particular.
  virtual typedef MyType; 
};

struct Derived : Base {
  // Won't compile unless this typedef exists.
  typedef int MyType;
};
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: What do you want this for? Knowing your goal will certainly make it better to get you an answer. And no, "emulating some random Scala feature" does not count as a goal.

Comment: @Xeo - The poster is "exploring  template shenanigans" - it's a contrived goal, but still a goal! :)

Comment: I'm implementing typeclasses in C++. (I know this has been done before, sorta, but nothing I've found is quite what I want.) In particular, if I want to write a generic typeclass that supports mapping, I need something like Scala's CanBuildFrom (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom). Doing this nicely seems to require virtual types.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure there is a real need for this in C++.

Trying to put myself in the position of a designer who is looking for such a solution, I would say this kind of constraint would be needed to enforce some types to adhere to some syntactic convention.

Most likely, this is needed because a generic algorithm requires that syntactic convention: it cannot work with types that do not define such a type association.

For instance, the algorithm below requires the type of its argument to have an associated `bar_type`:

```
template<typename T>
bool foo(T t)
{
    typedef typename T::bar_type FT;
    FT ft;
    ...
}
```

But if this is the case, there is no need for *enforcing* a `typedef` to effectively constraint the input of `foo<>()`: simply omitting a type definition for `bar_type` won't make it possible to use that type with `foo<>()`.

Of course, you would discover this only as soon as you actually *try* to do so, and not before. And being able to define a *concept* such as `HasBarType`, and then to enforce some types to realize that concept would be nice; on the other hand, concepts are not *yet* part of C++ and, as much as they are desirable, it is possible to live without them.

Comment: There's also `my_tag_type<T>::bar_type` if you want to be able to make existing 3rd party or primitive types fullfill your requirements.  See `std::iterator_traits<int*>::value_type`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Right, that's another way of enforcing it

Comment: @AndyProwl, you've hit the nail on the head re Concepts; I'm trying to force early compilation failure if a typeclass (basically a Concept, as I understand it) is not properly implemented.

Comment: @emchristiansen: Then I'm not sure if this is feasible with a "once and for all" declaration/assertion. In C++, I believe you still have to specify one declaration/assertion for each type explicitly: it could be *outside* those types, but I would say it must be present.

Answer (score 1):

*edit*

This doesn't work, but I think the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149336/practical-uses-for-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern) might be the way to go.

*/edit*

```
template<typename Dependent>
class Base : public Dependent {
    typedef typename Dependent::MyType MyType;
};
```

Then use the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149336/practical-uses-for-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern):

```
struct Derived : Base<Derived> {
  // Won't compile unless this typedef exists.
  typedef int MyType;
};
```

Comment: [Have you tried compiling that](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2x2bEe$8)? Btw, missing `typename` :-)

Comment: @PeterWood, I've tried to solve this generally with the CRTP, without success. The apparent problem: CRTP adds dependencies from Base to Derived, and when Derived has dependencies on Base you can get an infinite template loop.